# copy ant classpath jars to build folder

Tags: java, ant, build

This might be a repeated question but no solution is found so for.

I had made a build.xml for my new project under a developed environment.

```
<project name="env-agent-config-util" basedir=".">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>  
    <property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/UI/jar"/>
    <property name="main-class" value="org.env.agent.config.util.ProxySettings"/>
    <property name="env.src.dir" location="${env.ENV_SRC}/integration/java/server/conf"/>
    <property name="env.lib.dir" location="${env.ENV_JAVA_DEV}/lib/dir" />
    <import file="${evn.src.dir}/build.xml" optional="false" />

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init-common" >
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac  destdir="${classes.dir}">
            <src path="${src.dir}"/>
            <src path="${env.src.dir}"/>
            <classpath refid="env.utils.jars"/>
            <classpath refid="third.party.jars"/>
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${env.lib.dir}/integration/common/env-integration-common-crypto.jar" />
            </classpath>
        </javac>
        <copy todir="${build.dir}/UI/lib" flatten="true"> 
            <path>
               <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
            </path>
        <!--    <fileset dir="${env.lib.dir}" />    -->
        </copy>
       </target>
       <target name="jar" depends="compile">
           <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
           <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
           <manifest>
              <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
           </manifest>
        </jar>
     </target>
     <target name="run" depends="jar,clean">
        <echo message="All Runnable, Jar are placed into the Build/UI Folder."/>
        <!-- <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/> -->
     </target>


</project>
```

As you can see, i had made reference to 3 paths:

- env.util.jars
- third.party.jars
- ${env.lib.dir}/integration/common/env-integration-common-crypto.jar

Under current declaration i.e. ${java.class.path} under copy tag, it copies the file but jars name are changed. I don't want to do this.

I need to copy all jars (with their correct name) that falls under these path variables to build/UI/lib folder.

I tried to use fileset but it takes only current project variables.

At least how can I make a property variable for these path variables?

Kindly help...

Comment: Why are files being copied from `${java.class.path}`? `${java.class.path}` is the classpath of Ant itself. It contains the Ant and JDK libraries that Ant needs to run. `${java.class.path}` doesn't change after Ant begins. It won't contain anything specific to your build.

Comment: I had stop using libraries under ${java.class.path} instead I had made property(at the top of build.xml) referencing those libraries. Then I used that properties in my target.